# Python Annotate Two Exact Strings for Function Parameter

Tags: python, annotations, typing, pep8

Say I have a function `foo`, that takes in a parameter `a`. I would like to annotate the function to indicate that `a` should only accept 2 strings - `'string1'` and `'string2'`

What I currently have is (python<3.10):

```
from typing import Union

def foo(a: Union['string1', 'string2']):
    pass
```

Also, is there a way to indicate that a function returns a tuple of 2 sets of 2 data types?
i.e. `foo` would return a tuple of 2 strings and 2 ints, at the exact same position every time

```
from typing import Tuple

def foo() -> Tuple[int, str, int, str]:
    return 1, 's1', 2, 's2'
```

I would not like to go with `Tuple[int, str]` as the order should be annotated

Comment: What's wrong with what you have currently?

Comment: for the first example, mypy gives the error "Name 'string1' is not defined (mypy error)"

Comment: And the second example? It looks like it's unrelated to the first issue, so I would edit it out and posting a second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question (side note: please don't ask two separate question in one, it's more difficult to answer and search) is about [`Literal` type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/). It will be

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 8):
    from typing_extensions import Literal
else:
    from typing import Literal

def foo(a: Literal['string1', 'string2']) -> None:
    pass
```

Your second question is a bit odd, because the code you show is exactly what you need. `Tuple` accepts arbitrary number of type arguments (including `()` to specify empty tuple). `Tuple[int, str, int]` is a tuple of exactly 3 elements of types `int`, `str`, `int` in this specific order. Special case: `Tuple[int, ...]` (note literal ellipsis - it's part of syntax) represents tuple of arbitrary length containing only `int`'s. Tuple that contains any number of `int`'s or `str`'s will be `Tuple[Union[str, int], ...]`. Fixed-length tuple (without ellipsis) may contain any types. You can read more in [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtin_types.html).